Making a build for node js app with lots of apis
I have a codebase with Express & Node js as a framework. We have loads of apis to call for various operations and they're accessing third-party software. So some authentication is also involved. The issue is this:
We want to provide a exe file or some build to the client to test those APIs on their system.
But we can't share our codebase
Now we just want to create this exe file so that the server runs smoothly on the client PC.
So we'll also need to include all the files(the whole main folder in the exe)
Is there an efficient way to do this?
Thanks
Also here's the result of using nexe as a local module:

Error downloading prebuilt binary: RequestError: unable to get local issuer certificate

It'd be really helpful if anyone could shed some light on what is causing this error exactly & how can we fix this.

If you can't trust the client with the source code, you'll have to just decline their request. Building a binary version is a dead end.

The best option to achieve some privacy and a single distributable is to use some packing tool that packs the V8 and app in a single executable like PKG or nexe.
The error seems to be related with CA Certificate from the build machine. Probably there is no Root Certificate. Look at MMC on Windows and /etc/ssl/certs/ and /etc/ca-certificates.conf
Or try running this in node to validate download urls that nexe uses node sslcert.js https://nodejs.org/:
const https = require('https');

// Retrieve the URL from the command line arguments
const url = process.argv[2];

if (!url) {
    console.error('Please specify a URL as an argument.');
    process.exit(1);
}

https.get(url, (res) => {
    const cert = res.socket.getPeerCertificate();

    if (res.socket.authorized) {
        console.log('SSL Certificate is valid for:', url);
        console.log('Certificate details:', cert);
    } else {
        console.error('SSL Certificate validation failed for:', url);
        console.error('Reason:', res.socket.authorizationError);
    }
}).on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Error making the request:', err.message);
});


